# Ion Auth (Codeigniter) - How to use different database

Tags: codeigniter, ion-auth

Is it possible to use different database for authenticating user through Ion Auth?
I would like to create a database dedicated only for user authentication. So, it should be separated from transactional database. 
How to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: what database are you using ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Codeigniter - multiple database connections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268853/codeigniter-multiple-database-connections)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short...yes it is possible for you to use a different database for your authentication. You would need to create a second database configuration in your `application/config/database.php` file (similar to the below) in addition to your default config.

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['default']['username'] = "root";
$db['default']['password'] = "";
$db['default']['database'] = "db_name";
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";

$db['authentication']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['authentication']['username'] = "root";
$db['authentication']['password'] = "";
$db['authentication']['database'] = "auth_db_name";
$db['authentication']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
```

For further reference see - http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/configuration.html

You would then have to modify your ion_auth model to use this second db configuration, which you would set when loading the database.

```
$auth_db = $this->load->database('authentication', TRUE);
```

Then change all database queries in the model replacing `$this->db` with `$auth_db`.

So, `$this->db->select('password, salt')` would become `$auth_db->select('password, salt')`.

For further reference see - http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/connecting.html

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be to expand on what MY_Mark said.

Create the new DB config

```
$db['authentication']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['authentication']['username'] = "root";
$db['authentication']['password'] = "";
$db['authentication']['database'] = "auth_db_name";
$db['authentication']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
```

Then in the constructor of the ion_auth_model.php do this:

```
$this->db = $this->load->database('authentication', TRUE);
```

And it should just work after that.