# codeigniter insert data into two databases using localhost?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, localhost

I'm working on codeigniter application and application installed on localhost and web server but actually I want that is data should be insert in localhost database and web server database using localhost?

how do i connect web server database in database.php file and how to use web server connection in CI_Controller function?

Answer (score 0):

You can look this post [Codeigniter - multiple database connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268853/codeigniter-multiple-database-connections) 
but basically is like this
add this to database.php

```
$db['otherdb']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['otherdb']['username'] = "root";
$db['otherdb']['password'] = "";
$db['otherdb']['database'] = "other_database_name";
$db['otherdb']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$db['otherdb']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['otherdb']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['otherdb']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['otherdb']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['otherdb']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['otherdb']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['otherdb']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
$db['otherdb']['swap_pre'] = "";
$db['otherdb']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['otherdb']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

and you can call it from the model like this

```
function my_model_method()
{
  $otherdb = $this->load->database('otherdb', TRUE); // the TRUE paramater tells CI that you'd like to return the database object.

  $query = $otherdb->select('first_name, last_name')->get('person');
  var_dump($query);
}
```

Comment: please tell for how to insert into two database at once time?

Comment: i can't understand you send me example of insert?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
function my_model_method()
{
$otherdb = $this->load->database('otherdb', TRUE);
$data= array('name'=>'John');
$database1=$this->db->insert('students', $data); //default db
$database2 = $otherdb->insert('students',$data); //the other db
}
```

Comment: data inserted into live database not localhost database?

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "Live Database" you can configure the database server where ever you want , could be localhost or  from amazon
`    $db['db']['hostname'] = "localhost";
or
    $db['otherdb']['hostname'] = "mydbinstance.abcdefghijkl.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com";`