# How to conditionally use different database in CodeIgniter

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter

Here is my scenario.
A user will login to the system. Based on the username, I need to set the database in codeigniter configuration.
I know that the line `$this->load->database()` in each model loads the default database.
So, after checking the username in session(assuming that the user has successfully logged in), how can I dynamically load a database?

Below is something that I am looking for:

```
if(username == 'foo'){
    $this->load->database('database_name');
}
```

An example of a model function that I have written is as follows:

```
public function check_valid_login($username, $password){
    $this->db->from('tbl_user_details');
    $this->db->where('email_address', $username);
    $this->db->where('password', md5($password));
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $rowcount = $query->num_rows();
    return $rowcount ;
}
```

On selecting the database, how can I still use statements like `$this->db->from('tbl_user_details');` and so on. i.e., I want to use `$this->db` itself. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: follow the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268853/codeigniter-multiple-database-connections

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution.
This is the strategy that I followed: When the user tries to login, a session variable `$_SESSION['dynamic_db_username']` is set with the username that is provided by the user.
The following logic is used for selecting the database dynamically. The below code is written in `config/database.php`

```
/*Dynamic database selection - begins*/
if(!empty($_SESSION['dynamic_db_username'])){
    $dynamic_db_username = $_SESSION['dynamic_db_username'];

    if($dynamic_db_username == 'sample@domain.com')
    {
        $db['default']['database'] = 'database_1';
    }
    elseif($dynamic_db_username == 'sample2@domain.com')
    {
        $db['default']['database'] = 'database_2';
    }
    else
    {
        $db['default']['database'] = 'database_1';
    }
}
else
{
    $db['default']['database'] = 'database_1';
}

/*End*/
```

Kindly review this strategy and please let me know if this is right.

Answer (score 0):

in the config folder there was a file named autoload.php 
open the file

find first this code below

```
  $autoload['libraries'] = array('');
```

you have to put "database" in the array , changed code will be like

```
  $autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

after that you can use your database anytime and anywhere without loading it manually .

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the requirement is that I need to be able to select a database based on particular condition dynamically. - Thanks.