# Switch database server in codigniter for Read and Write Operations.

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I have done master and slave setup for my database server, so In my codigniter application what I want is to execute all write options on master server and all read operation on slave server.

Can anybody tell me how can I achieve this in codigniter version3.

Thanks.

Comment: you can have two database connection and whenever there is write operation use master object and whenever read use salve obj

Comment: Are you looking for this ??  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268853/codeigniter-multiple-database-connections

Comment: actully my application is already done and I don't want to create 2 seperate connection and don't want to edit  all applcation model files. so I am looking for codigniter hack which switch the DB on the fly for read and write operations

Comment: you can try with the system files present in database folder of systems

Comment: I have posted the answer and it is working as per requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have to update system/database/DB_Driver.php file.

Its very simple what you have to make 3 small changes in this file.

1) Inside Construction add your Read and Write server credentials.

```
        $this->server_details['local_server']['hostname'] = "localhost";
        $this->server_details['local_server']['username'] = "select_user";
        $this->server_details['local_server']['password'] = "password";       

        $this->server_details['live_server']['hostname'] = "192.192.223.22";  
        $this->server_details['live_server']['username'] = "write_user"; 
        $this->server_details['live_server']['password'] = "password";
```

2) Create New function will switch the database connection for select and write query.

```
 private function ebrandz_switch_db_for_read_write($sql) {               

       if( $this->hostname == $this->server_details['local_server']['hostname'] &&  $this->username == $this->server_details['local_server']['username'] &&  $this->password == $this->server_details['local_server']['password'] ) {    
                   //echo $sql.'<br/>';
         if(stristr($sql, 'SELECT')) {   
                            foreach($this->server_details['local_server'] as $index_key => $index_value ) { 
                                $this->$index_key = $index_value;  
                            }             

                              $this->conn_id = null;  //unset resource link 
                              $this->initialize();   //Reinitialize connnection with new parameters                                                                                                       

                    } else {    
                            //die('write operation is not allowed.');
                            foreach($this->server_details['live_server'] as $index_key => $index_value ) { 
                                 $this->$index_key = $index_value;  
                            }  
                            $this->conn_id = null ; //unset resource link 
                            $this->initialize();    //Reinitialize connnection with new parameters                                                           
                    }

               } else if( $this->hostname == $this->server_details['live_server']['hostname'] &&  $this->username == $this->server_details['live_server']['username']  &&  $this->password ==  $this->server_details['live_server']['password'] ) {  

                    if(stristr($sql, 'SELECT')) { 
                            foreach($this->server_details['local_server'] as $index_key => $index_value ) { 
                                 $this->$index_key = $index_value;  
                            }  

                            $this->conn_id = null ;  //unset resource link 
                            $this->initialize();     //Reinitialize connnection with new parameters      

                    } else {  
                            //die('write operation is not allowed.');
                            foreach($this->server_details['live_server'] as $index_key => $index_value ) { 
                                 $this->$index_key = $index_value;
                            } 

                            $this->conn_id = null ; //unset resource link 
                            $this->initialize();    //Reinitialize connnection with new parameters                                                           
                    }

               }

               //Code to re initialize the connection 
    }
```

3) Inside  Query function of this file you have to call the prevous defined function.

```
// Verify table prefix and replace if necessary
    if ($this->dbprefix !== '' && $this->swap_pre !== '' && $this->dbprefix !== $this->swap_pre)
    {
        $sql = preg_replace('/(\W)'.$this->swap_pre.'(\S+?)/', '\\1'.$this->dbprefix.'\\2', $sql);
    }

     /**
     * @author Anant Waykar
     * if query is read only then load some other database
     */
            $this->ebrandz_switch_db_for_read_write($sql);                     
      //Code to re initialize the connection
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the second database information in `application/config/database.php´

Normally, you would set the default database group, like so:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['default']['username'] = "root";
$db['default']['password'] = "";
$db['default']['database'] = "database_name";
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['default']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = "";
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Notice that the login information and settings are provided in the array named `$db['default']`.

You can then add another database in a new array - let's call it 'otherdb'.

```
$db['otherdb']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['otherdb']['username'] = "root";
$db['otherdb']['password'] = "";
$db['otherdb']['database'] = "other_database_name";
$db['otherdb']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$db['otherdb']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['otherdb']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['otherdb']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['otherdb']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['otherdb']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['otherdb']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['otherdb']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
$db['otherdb']['swap_pre'] = "";
$db['otherdb']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['otherdb']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

If you need to connect to more than one database simultaneously you can do so as follows:

```
$readDB = $this->load->database('otherdb', TRUE);

//For read:
$query = $readDB->select('first_name, last_name')->get('person');
var_dump($query);

//For write:
$this->db->insert('tablename', $insert_array);
```

Comment: I know this straight forward way what my requirement is keep  DB connection active and switch the server based on select or update query

Comment: Means you want to change switch server based on select or update query than you have to extend database libraray.

Comment: yes  actually my application is already running and have lots of model files, so I don't want to update each of this file

Comment: I checked and I don't think it is possible. But you have to change in system files.
Let me know if you resolved it.

Comment: Yes I know i have to changed the system files?