# how to set multiple databases with same localhost, root and password

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

application/config/
database.php, 
How can I set another database with same localhost,
Please help! thanks in Advance

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;
$db['default'] = array(
 'dsn' => '',
 'hostname' => 'localhost',
 'username' => 'root',
 'password' => '',
 'database' => 'business_permit',
 'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
 'dbprefix' => '',
 'pconnect' => FALSE,
 'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
 'cache_on' => FALSE,
 'cachedir' => '',
 'char_set' => 'utf8',
 'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
 'swap_pre' => '',
 'encrypt' => FALSE,
 'compress' => FALSE,
 'stricton' => FALSE,
 'failover' => array(),
 'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: refer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40894657/3635079

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter - multiple database connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268853/codeigniter-multiple-database-connections)

Answer (score 5):

The best way is to use different database groups. If you want to keep using the master database as usual (`$this->db`) just turn off persistent connection configuration option to your secondary database(s). Only master database should work with persistent connection :

Master database

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['default']['username'] = "root";
$db['default']['password'] = "";
$db['default']['database'] = "database_name";
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['default']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = "";
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Secondary database (notice pconnect is set to false)

```
$db['otherdb']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['otherdb']['username'] = "root";
$db['otherdb']['password'] = "";
$db['otherdb']['database'] = "other_database_name";
$db['otherdb']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$db['otherdb']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['otherdb']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['otherdb']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['otherdb']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['otherdb']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['otherdb']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['otherdb']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
$db['otherdb']['swap_pre'] = "";
$db['otherdb']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['otherdb']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Then you can use secondary databases as database objects while using master database as usual :

```
// use master dataabse
$users = $this->db->get('users');

// connect to secondary database
$otherdb = $this->load->database('otherdb', TRUE);
$stuff = $otherdb->get('struff');
$otherdb->insert_batch('users', $users->result_array());

// keep using master database as usual, for example insert stuff from other database
$this->db->insert_batch('stuff', $stuff->result_array());
```

Hopes answered your question.
Google first before you ask the question... ;)

[Codeigniter - multiple database connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268853/codeigniter-multiple-database-connections)

Comment: Where to put this

Comment: // use master dataabse
$users = $this->db->get('users');

// connect to secondary database
$otherdb = $this->load->database('otherdb', TRUE);
$stuff = $otherdb->get('struff');
$otherdb->insert_batch('users', $users->result_array());

// keep using master database as usual, for example insert stuff from other database
$this->db->insert_batch('stuff', $stuff->result_array());

Comment: Just go to `application > config > database.php`
Make sure your database has been set in `autoload.php`

Comment: @J.A.Manato
You may refer this link for further details
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/index.html

Answer (score 0):

you have use environment to use multiple database

- create config folder inside  production and development folder and add database.php file
- then root path index.php file set environment