# connect to another db in codeigniter and insert

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

i am trying to connect to another db and insert data , data is properly inserting in the first db but does not insert in the second db , all the fields being the same in both the tables , the code below does not insert in the latestdb, below is my model code, I am quite sure that controller and views are fine , Please let  me know if more details are required. I am using codeigniter 2. The problem is after the comment // Insert in pr_users

```html
$this->db->$function($this->myTables['users'], $data);
    $db1['latestdb']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
    $db1['latestdb']['username'] = 'root';
    $db1['latestdb']['password'] = 'passw';
    $db1['latestdb']['database'] = 'latestdb';
    $db1['latestdb']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
    $db1['latestdb']['dbprefix'] = '';
    $db1['latestdb']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
    $db1['latestdb']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
    $db1['latestdb']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
    $db1['latestdb']['cachedir'] = '';
    $db1['latestdb']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
    $db1['latestdb']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
    $db1['latestdb']['swap_pre'] = '';
    $db1['latestdb']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
    $db1['latestdb']['stricton'] = FALSE;
   
   
    $DB2 = $this->load->database($db1, TRUE);
    $DB2->db_select('zipbizzlatestdb');
    $DB2->$function($this->myTables['users'], $data);

    $DB2->insert('pr_users',$data);
```

I am getting error saying :

An Error Was Encountered

You have not selected a database type to connect to.

Comment: Check this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268853/codeigniter-multiple-database-connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268853/codeigniter-multiple-database-connections)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify

```
$DB2 = $this->load->database($db1);
```

To

```
// TRUE parameter tells CI that you'd like to return the database object.
$DB2 = $this->load->database($db1, TRUE);
```

**Also note**

> You don’t need to create separate database configurations if you only
>   need to use a different database on the same connection. You can
>   switch to a different database when you need to, like this:

```
$this->db->db_select('database2_name');
```

and

```
$this->$DB2->your_function( ... )

 ^
  Does not have any such property
```

To

```
$DB2->your_function( .. )
```

Comment: not working , something is wrong, the database config is already having the configuration

Comment: @sunshine, one more problem `$DB2->your_function( .. )` is correct, not `$this->$DB2->your_function( ... )`

Comment: Please see the updated question, I am Now getting An Error Was Encountered You have not selected a database type to connect to, but already i have mentioned the db driver to connect to

Comment: @sunshine: you already loaded database config, then no need of `$DB2->db_select('zipbizzlatestdb');`, also if you are change db driver `mysql` to `mysqli`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this in your** 
**Modal**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Test extends CI_Model {

  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->another = $this->load->database("anotherdb",true);
  } 

  function get()
  {
    $this->another->select("*");
    $this->another->from("admin");
    $query = $this->another->get();
    return $query->result();
  } 
}
?>
```