# CodeIgniter get view tables of another database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

During development, we had to sign a view table of another database, but no matter how hard we tried, only an error occurred. So even though I just called it a simple select, an error occurs.

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1046 No database selected
>
> ```
> SELECT * 
> FROM `test1`.`view_test_table`
> ```
>
> Filename: test.php

I don't understand this situation.

I've done everything I've asked CodeIgniter document to do, and I've done everything from simple queries to query builder tests, but I can't see the details.

Test_mode.php is:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Test_model extends CI_Model
{
    private $new_db;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->new_db = $this->load->database('test1', TRUE);
    }

    public function test_view_list()
    {
       $this->new_db->select("*");
       $this->new_db->from("test1.view_test_table");
       return $this->new_db->get()->result_array();
    }
}
```

and database.php

```
$db['test1'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'test1',
    'password' => 'xxxx',
    'database' => '',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
 );
```

Did I make any mistakes?

Comment: Have you read through the documentation?

Comment: Did you have a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/8269596

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer - I think there was a slight misunderstanding because it was used for the first time. I'll be careful from now on.

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi - https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/index.html

Comment: @digijay - thanks. but, I've already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your database.php file.
 write your database name.

```
$db['test1'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'test1',
    'password' => 'xxxx',
    'database' => 'databasename',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
 );
```

Comment: Thanks... it work!!  I feel so empty. I spent a lot of time looking for it, but it was so simple. Still, I am very grateful for your help. but... Is that how it's perceived? Can't it work if I put it in the from syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a new  instance for this db

```
$new_db = $this->load->database('test1', TRUE);
```

and refer tor the table `view_test_table` using new_db

Comment: Thank you so much :D, but I've already tried. update my source