# Execute SQL query using second database in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I want to get the data from the second database connected to Codeigniter using a SQL query.

Sample code :

```
$db2 = $this->load->database('second_db', true);
$product_id = implode(",", $product_id);
$query = $db2->prepare("SELECT * FROM rt_product_details WHERE id IN ($product_id)");

if ($query->execute()) {
    $result = $query->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    var_dump($result);die;
}
```

Comment: So??? What is the issue you are facing? Any error? Please write something you are getting..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter - multiple database connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268853/codeigniter-multiple-database-connections)

Comment: In your code, I can see, CI Active Records + MySQLi . ..

Comment: what's your output/ error ?

Comment: Dont forget that if the connecting user has privileges you can connect to a second database by doing `second_db.rt_product_details` in your select query on your existing $db connection.