# Update Local and Web database from codeigniter website

Tags: database, sqlite, codeigniter

I have a Codeigniter website that is hosted on a global server and connected to the global database.
I want to connect another database that is hosted locally(192.168.x.x).
Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268853/codeigniter-multiple-database-connections

Comment: do you mean with _locally_ your database in your `dev` environment ? If so, take a look at https://superuser.com/questions/1335553/mapping-domain-name-with-local-ip-address for a better understanding

Answer (score 0):

In real-world CodeIgniter projects, developers need to work with multiple databases at the same time. This presents a unique challenge to developers. Since this is a common enough problem, CodeIgniter offers a simple solution for it.

In order to use multiple database connections in your CodeIgniter project, you just need to create multiple configuration arrays that simplify working with multiple databases.

**The Default Configuration Array**
Following is the structure of the default Codeigniter database configuration array:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'mydefaultdatabase';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['autoinit'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
```

So in order to create **another database connection**, you should create another configuration array. This array has to follow the same structure. Here is an example of the array:

```
$db['anotherdb']['hostname'] = 'XXX.XXX.X.XXX';
$db['anotherdb']['username'] = 'another_user';
$db['anotherdb']['password'] = '';
$db['anotherdb']['database'] = 'anotherdatabase';
$db['anotherdb']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['anotherdb']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['anotherdb']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['anotherdb']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['anotherdb']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['anotherdb']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['anotherdb']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['anotherdb']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['anotherdb']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['anotherdb']['autoinit'] = FALSE;
$db['anotherdb']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

**Connect to the Right Database**

At this point, you have two databases in your sample project. To connect to a specific database, you must specify the database name. Here is the proper syntax:

```
this->load->database(anotherdb, TRUE)
```

After connecting to the database, you can perform databse operations as shown below:
**load 'anotherdatabase'**

```
$this->legacy_db = $this->load->database(anotherdatabase, true);
```

**Fetch result from 'mydefaultdatabase'**

```
$this->legacy_db->select ('*');
$this->legacy_db->from ('mydefaultdatabase');
$query = $this->legacy_db->get();
$result = $query->result ();
```

Now if you need to work with the second database, you have to send the connection to a variable that is usable in your **model** function:

```
function db_calling_model_method()
{
   $otherdb = $this->load->database('anotherdb', TRUE); // the TRUE paramater tells CI that you'd like to return the database object.
   $query = $otherdb->select('column_one, column_two')->get('table');
   var_dump($query);
}
```

**Close the Connections**

CodeIgniter does close the database connections after it determines that the code no longer need the connection. However, as a good practice, developers should close the connections explicitly. Here is how to take care of the issue:

```
$this->db->close(); // for default Connection
$this->legacy_db->close(); //
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Actually the issue is I need to connect two different databases. Among them, one is presented in my local environment and another one is presented globally. How  can I connect the local environment database(192.168.x.x)