# show error when codeigniter join with multiple database tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter-3

show Call to a member function num_rows() on boolean when I going to join with two different database on production. on localhost working fine

my code is below :

$this->db->select('livedb.ADMIN_TEAM.id');
$this->db->from('livedb.ADMIN_TEAM');

```
          $this->db->join("olap.SL_DEMO_ACTIVITY_COUNT","(olap.SL_DEMO_ACTIVITY_COUNT.admin_id = livedb.ADMIN_TEAM.id) AND (olap.SL_DEMO_ACTIVITY_COUNT.assign_date='".$preData."')" ,"LEFT");
          $this->db->join("olap.SL_DEMO_ACTIVITY_COUNT","(olap.SL_DEMO_ACTIVITY_COUNT.admin_id = newforce_livedb.ADMIN_TEAM.id)" ,"LEFT");
          
          $this->db->where('livedb.ADMIN_TEAM.team_status','1');
          $this->db->where('livedb.ADMIN_TEAM.team_type','sales');
          $this->db->where('livedb.ADMIN_TEAM.id !=','129');
          $this->db->where('livedb.ADMIN_TEAM.sale_type','CRM');
          $this->db->limit('1');
          $this->db->order_by('livedb.ADMIN_TEAM.id','ASC');
          $query = $this->db->get();
          print_r($this->db->last_query());    

          if( $query->num_rows() > 0 ){
              return $query->result();
          }
          else {     return FALSE; }
```

Comment: Have you tried executing your query directly on your client? What error it is throwing?

Comment: yes tried my query on phpmyadmin directly then its working fine

Comment: Have you tried it on your production DB or on localhost?

Comment: I tried it on production db phpmyadmin there is working fine
but it show error when it execute from postman using with CodeIgniter syntax or php

Comment: on localhost is working form al side

Comment: Check if codeigniter is able to connect to all the databases that you are using.

Comment: I already connect two database in CodeIgniter
But first time try to join with different db tables in single query

Comment: I don't see the other db object in your code. How are you loading the other/secondary DB?

Comment: i am loading other db object by using db name 

otherDb.user.admin_id

first is db name ,second is table name, third is table field name

Comment: can you help me to define other db object in my code.

Comment: Please check this [Codeigniter - multiple database connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268853/codeigniter-multiple-database-connections)